# function for all possible regression models in model selection

Tags: r, multiple-regression, feature-selection, model-selection

I have a linear regression model:

$Y~X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5+X_6+X_7+X_8+X_9$ and I need to create a function that find all possible models (e.g.

- $Y = X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4$
- $Y = X_2+X_3+X_4$
- $Y = X_1+X_3+X_4+X_5+X_6$ etc) and then calculates each model's DIC values.

Can someone help me since I'm not experienced at programming?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why do you want this technique? Is it to find the most overfit model?

Comment: It's in the context of my internship project where I have to use different model selection criteria for a given dataset

Comment: See the `dredge` function in package MuMIn.

Comment: R has a package for all possible subsets: leaps (on CRAN)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just use a backward or forward method to do so.

Forward: Just add and remove all your independent variables and see how each variable affect the model. Then keep adding and subtracting variables until you got a good model.

Backward: Add all variables and then remove them one by one and readd them to evaluate your model.

Comment: On could argue that "just use" should rather be replaced with "don't use": http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection/20856#20856

Comment: Fitting every model and using a criterion (AIC, BIC, BICc) is a valid way to do model selection for a small number of predictors. Backwards and forward variable selection have fallen out of favor because they produce highly variable results.

Comment: This algorithm does not explore the "all possible subsets" of models requested in the question.